# Elasticsearch issue in openshift cluster" failed to obtain node locks, tried [[/usr/share/elasticsearch/data]] with lock id [0] "

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, openshift

I'm trying to run Elasticsearch in cluster mode inside kubernets and I'm getting below error when trying to create the POD.

I have already found many approaches for this error. Unfortunately none of them helped me to solve my problem. I have set node.max_local_storage_nodes: 20, it also not working

> OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was
>   deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future
>   release.
>       {"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-01-15T17:32:21,100Z", "level": "WARN", "component":
>   "o.e.b.ElasticsearchUncaughtExceptionHandler", "cluster.name":
>   "mih-dev", "node.name": "es-cluster-0", "message": "uncaught exception
>   in thread [main]", 
>       "stacktrace": ["org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.StartupException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to obtain node locks, tried
>   [[/usr/share/elasticsearch/data]] with lock id [0]; maybe these
>   locations are not writable or multiple nodes were started without
>   increasing [node.max_local_storage_nodes] (was [1])?",
>       "at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:163)
>   ~[elasticsearch-7.4.1.jar:7.4.1]",
>       "at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:150)
>   ~[elasticsearch-7.4.1.jar:7.4.1]",
>       "at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:86)
>   ~[elasticsearch-7.4.1.jar:7.4.1]",
>       "at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:125)
>   ~[elasticsearch-cli-7.4.1.jar:7.4.1]",
>       "at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:90) ~[elasticsearch-cli-7.4.1.jar:7.4.1]",
>       "... 6 more",
>       "Caused by: java.io.IOException: failed to obtain lock on /usr/share/elasticsearch/data/nodes/0",
>       "at org.elasticsearch.env.NodeEnvironment$NodeLock.(NodeEnvironment.java:221)
>   ~[elasticsearch-7.4.1.jar:7.4.1]",
>       "at org.elasticsearch.env.NodeEnvironment.(NodeEnvironment.java:269)
>   ~[elasticsearch-7.4.1.jar:7.4.1]",
>       "... 6 more",
>       "Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data/nodes/0/node.lock",
>       "at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:92)
>   ~[?:?]",
>       "at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:111)
>   ~[?:?]",
>       "at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:116)
>   ~[?:?]",
>       "... 6 more",
>       "Suppressed: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data/nodes/0/node.lock",
>       "\tat sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:90)
>   ~[?:?]",
>       "\tat sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:111)
>   ~[?:?]",
>       "\tat sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:116)
>   ~[?:?]",
>       "\tat sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:219)
>   ~[?:?]",

Here is my Openshift Stateful set YAML

```
kind: StatefulSet
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: es-cluster
  namespace: mih-dev
  generation: 1
  labels:
    app: elasticsearch
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: elasticsearch
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: elasticsearch
    spec:
      containers:
        - resources:
            limits:
              cpu: '1'
            requests:
              cpu: 100m
          terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
          name: elasticsearch
          env:
            - name: cluster.name
              value: mih-dev
            - name: node.name
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  apiVersion: v1
                  fieldPath: metadata.name
            - name: discovery.seed_hosts
              value: >-
                es-cluster-0.elasticsearch,es-cluster-1.elasticsearch,es-cluster-2.elasticsearch
            - name: cluster.initial_master_nodes
              value: elasticsearch
            - name: ES_JAVA_OPTS
              value: '-Xms512m -Xmx512m'
          ports:
            - name: rest
              containerPort: 9200
              protocol: TCP
            - name: inter-node
              containerPort: 9300
              protocol: TCP
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          volumeMounts:
            - name: data
              mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
          terminationMessagePolicy: File
          image: 'docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.5.1'
      restartPolicy: Always
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      securityContext: {}
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
  volumeClaimTemplates:
    - metadata:
        name: data
        creationTimestamp: null
        labels:
          app: elasticsearch
      spec:
        accessModes:
          - ReadWriteOnce
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 5Gi
        storageClassName: gp2
      status:
        phase: Pending
  serviceName: elasticsearch
  podManagementPolicy: OrderedReady
  updateStrategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      partition: 0
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
```